# Suppress click event using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an html button that is being rendered as HTML like such:

```
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvAttendants','Select$0')" />
```

I'm attempting to use JQuery to suppress the click event of the above input tag, but I can't figure out how to do it! The button still does a postback, and I don't want it to.

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").click(function($e) {
            $e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't remove the onclick handler like that. All you're doing is attaching yet another click handler. Try this:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").removeAttr('onclick');
```

Also make sure your code is wrapped around document.ready

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `return false` in your `click` handler.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also do an unbind method:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").unbind("click");

//to check
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").bind("click", function(){alert("it runs only");});
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the button is being rendered by a ASP.NET control. In that case, I'd remove the onClick attribute. This may still cause a postback:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Alternatively, you can disable the button:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Select']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to add the "disabled" attribute. I'm going to do that as well.

Comment: Oh, and you are quite correct, the control is being rendered from a GridView CommandField.